# The type does not found in the namespace

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I'm trying to use a type from another project in the same solution but It marking my type in zigzag blue and writes that the type doesn't exist in the namespace that I refer to.
I've been trying to look for a solution but I couldn't find one.

These types are types that wasn't originally created in this namespace.

But even if I create new class and just copying the code it does not solve my problem.
And if I remove the namespaces from the references it turns red and not blue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the namespace in front of the class name.